# Clear cache on windows server 2012

Tags: css, caching, windows-server-2012-r2

I am in the process of updating some style sheets in a web app, however, each time i save the file the changes does not take effect. I do not want to stop or restart the server, any other options?

Iv already recycle the app but it still does not take in affect.

I am expecting to make the style changes to the app without stoping or restarting the server but they seem to be caching.

Answer (score 0):

So a longer term solution for this was to export the caching issue to a software called imperva and buffer our security in which in turn help purge cache when making changes.  Not sure if this is the solution for most of you as the "recycle" button should work in most cases but since we wanted a buffer of security we decided to go this route.